# Password column from sys.user$ is null in 18c, why?

Tags: oracle

Why the password column from sys.user$ is null? My version is 18c. I've made a test.

```
SQL> alter user harry identified by 12345678;

User altered.

SQL> select name,password from sys.user$ where name = 'HARRY';

NAME                           PASSWORD
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
HARRY

SQL>
```

I'd like to use the password from harry in another user with

```
alter user some_user identified by values 'hash_here'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the SPARE4 column.

Quoting from https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/855/How-Oracle-Stores-Passwords.html

> 11g introduces new security and the ability to support case sensitive
> passwords.
>
> First, DBA_USERS no longer exposes the PASSWORD value, instead it will
> be NULL and you will have to go to SYS.USER$ to find the hash value.
>
> However, if your PASSWORD_VERSIONS does not contain 10g then
> SYS.USER$.PASSWORD will not be reliable.  The reason is the hashing
> algorithm populating that field doesn't support case sensitivity.  So,
> regardless of the sensitivity setting and regardless of the upper or
> lower case of your password the hash will be the same.  If your
> PASSWORD_VERSIONS is 11g only then you will need to look in the
> SYS.USER$.SPARE4 column and you will see a much larger hex number.
> This is because Oracle has switched to the SHA-1
> (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) algorithm.